# qTip2 - show a different target

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I try to create a function that opens a bubble on an image when I click on any button :

```
$(document).on('click', '#MyButton', Check_Index);
function Check_Index() {
    $('img').qtip({
        content: {text:"hello !"}
    });
};
```

In this case, the bubble opens when I pass the smile on the image after clicking the button. But this is not what I want ...

You can see the demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/qtyTJ/206/

And you can see the plugin here : http://qtip2.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show immediately after click button just add next code

```
$(document).on('click', '#MyButton', Check_Index);

function Check_Index() {
        $('img').qtip({
            content: {text:"hello !"},
            show: true
         });
};
```

Also you can use hide option, for example

```
     $('img').qtip({
        content: {text:"hello !"},
        show: true,
        hide: {
            delay: 300
        }
    });
```

See this [demos](http://qtip2.com/demos)

To access qtip api you can do this:

```
// Create the tooltip first using regular .qtip() call
var tooltips = $('.selector').qtip({
    /* configuration options here */
});

// Grab the first element in the tooltips array and access its qTip API
var api = tooltips.qtip('api');
```

So now you can access api

```
api.hide();
api.show();
```

All api documentation you can find in [this place](http://qtip2.com/api#api.hide)

Comment: it's possible you think to hide tip `if(condition ){$('#imagechoix').qtip({hide: true});}` ?

Comment: @muramasa no problem ask)

Comment: Do you know why my tip appears when I pass the mouse over the image after clicking `show` then `hide` ? http://jsfiddle.net/qtyTJ/207/